# Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation of Authority using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-drive-api, federated-identity, google-api-js-client

Google doc ( https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object ) says:

```
For security reasons service accounts are not supported in client-side
Javascript. Service accounts for server-side Javascript is not yet
supported
```

I want to know is there any idea to implement it via php.
The following code will depicts my thought.

```
<?php $token = generateToken() ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  TOKEN = <?php echo $token ?>;
  startDriveRead(TOKEN);

</script>
```

The user defined php function `generateToken()` will do the federated authentication(it is possible) and will return the token(I don't know how to get the token).

The user defined JavaScript function `startDriveRead(`) will use the token from the server side and will access the drive data ( I don't know whether it is possible or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a javascript controller that works asynchronously to call back the server and perform the requests in php? I have yet to see a way to get a visible auth token when using the domain wide delegation of authority method to connect to google accounts.

Comment: I think that will be slower. The request has to go to our server then google server. If you are using javascript only, the request is going directly to google server. I fear that it will give more load to server.

Comment: yeah, but it looks like they use php sessions as part of the authentication process. If your php json encodes the object google sends back, the rest of the thinking could easily be done client-side. It is pretty low server load for most processes. Though if you are doing a lot of large file manipulation it could be an issue moving them back and forth. If you are client-side anyways, why not let the user go through oAuth2 process and then you can use the javascript library without too much trouble.

Comment: My intention is to avoid oAuth2 and make use of "Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation of Authority"

Comment: Rather than use the php client library to create your JWT and authenticate, if you follow the instructions on this page, you should be able to get a token... once you have that you could see if passing that token to the javascript function works: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: I hope the doc will help me. Let me work on it. I will update you once I completed it.